# Ignore onTap action on Transparent part of the svg image flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, gesturedetector, ontap

Issue is that their are multiple svg images in stack. I need them to trigger only when the user tapped on filled part of the svg. So that, when it ignores on transparent part of the image, it can able to trigger behind svg image.

```
        Stack(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => updateSelectedPart(1),
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/images/1.svg',
                color: selectedPart == 1
                    ? Colors.red
                    : Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => updateSelectedPart(2),
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/images/2.svg',
                color: selectedPart == 2
                    ? Colors.red
                    : Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => updateSelectedPart(3),
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
              child: AbsorbPointer(
                absorbing: true,
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/images/3.svg',
                  excludeFromSemantics: true,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                  color: selectedPart == 3
                      ? Colors.red
                    : Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Stack tap event will be prioritized bottom to top, it depends on what you are using for tap event, it would be easy if you could provide sample snippet that will reproduce your issue.

Comment: You can use `pointer-events:fill`  in CSS or as an attribute. Please read about [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events)

Comment: Added snippet please check

Comment: Can you have a look again @YeasinSheikh

Comment: I am not sure how to handle specific part with svg, but can be used Clipped widget to have boundary on tap area and here  tap priority `images/3` > `images/2`... if you like to have tap event on all you can play with `behavior`

Answer (score -1):

Ordering is bottom to top so you will need to adjust (change order in the stack) so that what might overlay another SVGs transparent part gets triggered on an action (click/touch event) not the SVG below it (Above it in this case as its bottom to top)